# Arrange selected vertices in a Circle

Tags: modeling, add-on

How do I arrange selected vertices into a circular formation quickly?

The other answers does not have the same title as my question. My question is direct and simple for younger beginner to search for results.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If they are planar:

Mesh > Transform > To Sphere (with weight 1). <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> (+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Found out that the Add-on Loop tools > Circle option works the same way. Thanks for the alternative method. But this method does have more control on how much "roundness" you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @hawkenfox, didn't know about loop tools before now. Loop tools gives me waaayyy better results on asymmetrical vertices.